# Highlight a pattern found

Tags: perl, search

I made a small web application with a search box. I wanted to highlight the words found in the search.

```
foreach my $article (@{$search_articles}) {
    my @result;

    foreach my $word (split(' ', $article->{content})) {
        if ( $word =~ params->{search} ) {
            push(@result,
                '<span style="background: yellow">' . $word . '</span>');
        }
        else {
            push(@result, $word);
        }
    }

    $article->{content} = join(' ', @result);
}
```

It's a little wordy.  It is certainly possible to make cleaner, and I'd like to have your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your search input is plain characters (i.e., no `<`, `>`, and likes), this is still problematic as can ruin your HTML code. Let's say I search for "border" in a page that contains `<table border="1">`, or "class" in virtually any page written in the past 5 years,... IMO, this stuff is better done using a DOM parser and then searching just plain text.

Now, to comment the search itself... Let us assume that the word from your search box is contained in the variable `$search`. I think this is better done like this:

```
foreach my $article (@{$search_articles}) {
    $article->{content} =~ s/\Q$word\E/<span style="background: yellow">$&<\/span>/g
}
```